# Android get OS clock according to user preferences

Tags: android

I stumbled on something I never thought of before! For some logging purpose I have a locilized timestamp in my Android application, which is achieved by following code snippet

```
String timeStamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

This works fine and give me a time stamp according to the devices locale.
However what I would like to get is a localized timestamp just containing hour:minute, some locale has 12 hour clock and others 24 hours. Is there some default functionality for this in Android or java, or do I have to find out the devices locale and make a decision from that which clock format to use

UPDATE

Okey, my question seems to be unclear and I can agree with that. 
What I would like to achieve is to get the time displayed in the notification bar. A time shown either in 24 or 12 h format depending on users setting. 
It would be convenient if I somehow could get that via som functionality in Android, without getting the time now and formatting it and so on, but I havn't found any. See my own answer on how a solved it for now.

Also removing Java tag as this question is specific to Android.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Apparently I need to figure out the locale myself and use a correct SimpleDate format depending on that. @BrianRoach, note that wasn't an asnwer on my question, I did know that, what I wonder is if there are any way to get current time from the Android device using correct locale, without using SimpleDateFormat. I mean the OS is already displaying that information so why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're talking about. You are saying you want a format that *isn't* defined by a locale, then start talking about locales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer my own question. I made a little convenience method to accomplish this, not exactly what I wanted but it does the job.

```
private String getLocalizedHHMMStamp(Context context) {
    Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

    // Different formatters for 12 and 24 hour timestamps
    SimpleDateFormat formatter24 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter12 = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a");

    // According to users preferences the OS clock is displayed in 24 hour format
    if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) {
        return formatter24.format(now);
    }

    return formatter12.format(now);
}
```

Using import:

```
android.text.format.*
```